# Linux, Parity, Ethereum and EthMiner

Tags: linux, openethereum

I just started playing with Ethereum mining on a Linux box. I lost a considerable amount of time installing Parity (https://www.parity.io/ethereum/) on the machine.

Then I created an account using W3, installed EthMiner, I connected to a pool (first one that I found in Google, which was cruxpool.com) then I started mining.

Do I need Parity at all? Why would anybody go to the trouble of installing Parity in the first place? Looks like you can mine quite fine without it. Someone can pls explain what is the added value with Parity?

Thank you

Comment: If you mine through a pool you don't need to run an ethereum client like parity (now openethereum). If you want to solo mine then you need a ethereum client running.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that!